# ExternalEvaluate Error

Tags: external-calls, javascript

I have installed NodeJS.

```
session = StartExternalSession["NodeJS"];
```

And I ran the comci.js file. comci.js file URL ( [enter link description here](http://naver.me/5KZb3FB4))

However, the result of ExternalEvaluate is not load. What is wrong?****

[image]

Comment: what is `org.jsoup.Jsoup` on line 2? Mathematica is passing NodeJS error.

Comment: It's in comci.js code.

Comment: `org` is not defined in `comci.js`, you should define `org` before using it.